# Google Movies showing placeholder images

Tags: google-movies

I have been using [Google Movie Showtimes](//google.com/movies) to browse movies. However recently
something has happened with the site, and the movie posters have all been
replaced with placeholder images:

> [image: showtimes]

What can I do about this problem?

Comment: FWIW I just see a broken image (I don't even see the placeholder image) for _all_ photos on the page (including movie screenshots). I'm non-US.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: the images have been restored.

---

Movie showtimes can now be accessed from the main page, so they may be phasing
out the dedicated movie page. Example:

http://google.com/search?q=movies+near+dallas

> [image: movies near dallas]